# Eclipse Juno/Indigo svn: E210004: Number is larger than maximum

Tags: svn, subversive, svnkit

The dialog box says:

```
Location information has been specified incorrectly.
svn: E210004: Number is larger than maximum
Keep location anyway?
```

This just started to occur. I updated the SVN server to 1.8.  It was working fine with 1.7.9.
I'm using svn+ssh. I have the latest updates (todate) of SVN Subversive and connector SVNKit 1.7.9.

BTW, this still works from the command line just fine.

Comment: I coordinate a tiny development team using Eclipse/SVN and various operating systems. I'm frequently fighting weirdness with SVN. I'm about ready to see if the git integration in Luna is better. My head hurts and all I wanna do is write my code.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same bug under Eclipse with Subclipse 1.8.22 after upgrading my Subversion server from 1.6.12 to 1.8.3.

I solved my problem by upgrading my client to Subclipse 1.10.2 (SVNKit 1.8).

For Netbeans, as SVNKit 1.8 has not been integrated yet (but hope it will be soon), you can specify a commandline client (menu Tools/Options/Misc/versioning/Subversion/Preferred client). This should work with any svn client version from 1.6 to 1.8 (and maybe older).

Check Netbeans FAQ about this incompatibility and workaround: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversion1_8

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, updating Subclipse client to 1.10.x fixes the problem in both Eclipse and Aptana.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled system and found out that old plugin in Eclipse supports 1.7.x but server version is 1.8.x

Syncing single files in Eclipse works correctly but above problem occurs when syncing whole project. I downgraded server version to [Subversion 1.7.x](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.14/apache22/) and it started working correctly. Probably the same results will be after upgrading plugin but I did not check if newer [Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php) supports 1.8.x. Check release notes of the plugin and server.

So check out what version of the plugin you have and what version of the server you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Luna version and sublipse 1.6.x, after my server upgraded to 1.8 version.

Upgrading the subclipse client works, but I figured out that changing the workspake (without upgrading plugin) works too.

I didn't find which metadata causes this behaviour, but with a brand new workspace it's ok.

It's always better I guess to upgrade subclipse, but for those who can't do it, I hope the answer can help.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand, but I thought that it answered the question, exactly the same way Nico answered the Sep 12 '13 at 13:15. But instead of upgrading Subclipse, you can also use a new workspace... What did I miss ?

Comment: Just to precise, why am I been told "If you have a different question" in the message above ? This is NOT a question, it's an answer. But not a correct one according to comments above, I won't argue more (even if I had the same issue and I solved it the way I explained).  Do I need to delete the answer, or is it done my someone else ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem on Eclipse Indigo. I solved it by just going on Window->Preferences->Team->SVN and changed the SVN Interface Client to JavaHL.